# How to center a footer

Tags: html, css, footer

Can anybody help my center this specific footer:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" 
    bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container">
  <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
    <footer text-align="center">
      <p class="style2">
        <br />
        Klik <a href="^OptOut:ProjectLink^">her</a>, hvis du ikke 
        ønsker at modtage flere invitationer til undersøgelsen.&nbsp;
      </p>
      <p class="style2">
        XX afdækker hvert år kundernes oplevelser i en række 
        forskellige brancher. <a href="^OptOut:PanelLink^">Klik 
        her</a>, hvis du ønsker at afmelde alle invitationer til XXs 
        undersøgelser fremover.
      </p>
      <p class="style2">
        XX gennemfører XX. Ved at påbegynde din besvarelse accepterer 
        du, at vi må indsamle og behandle dine data i henhold til 
        <a href="https://survey.euro.confirmit.com/isa/POADCB/AutoIndex/autoindex_dk_samtykke_confirmit.html"              
          target="_blank" rel="noopener">dette samtykke</a>. 
          Det er frivilligt at deltage i undersøgelsen.
        </p>
      <p class="style2"> </p>
    </footer>
  </table>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add (some relevant parts) of your CSS code to your code snippet? In that way we could provide a CSS solution that fits your case.

Comment: can you be a little more specific?

Comment: What is 'style2'? You have a footer inside a table inside a table. The HTML is invalid. Work on fixing that first.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `style` attribute on the `<footer>` tag

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container">
  <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
    <footer style="text-align:center; display:flex;
    flex-direction:column; justify-content:center;"
            ><p class="style2"><br />Klik <a href="^OptOut:ProjectLink^">her</a>, hvis du ikke ønsker at modtage flere invitationer til undersøgelsen.&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="style2">XX afdækker hvert år kundernes oplevelser i en række forskellige brancher. <a href="^OptOut:PanelLink^">Klik her</a>, hvis du ønsker at afmelde alle invitationer til XXs undersøgelser fremover.</p>
<p class="style2">XX gennemfører XX. Ved at påbegynde din besvarelse accepterer du, at vi må indsamle og behandle dine data i henhold til <a href="https://survey.euro.confirmit.com/isa/POADNDJYMRIOOXCAEPPIMTPDIIFRGQCB/AutoIndex/autoindex_dk_samtykke_confirmit.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">dette samtykke</a>. Det er frivilligt at deltage i undersøgelsen.</p>
        <p class="style2"> </p>
    </footer>
  </table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```css
footer{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" 
    bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container">
  <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
    <footer>
      <p class="style2">
        <br />
        Klik <a href="^OptOut:ProjectLink^">her</a>, hvis du ikke 
        ønsker at modtage flere invitationer til undersøgelsen.&nbsp;
      </p>
      <p class="style2">
        XX afdækker hvert år kundernes oplevelser i en række 
        forskellige brancher. <a href="^OptOut:PanelLink^">Klik 
        her</a>, hvis du ønsker at afmelde alle invitationer til XXs 
        undersøgelser fremover.
      </p>
      <p class="style2">
        XX gennemfører XX. Ved at påbegynde din besvarelse accepterer 
        du, at vi må indsamle og behandle dine data i henhold til 
        <a href="https://survey.euro.confirmit.com/isa/POADCB/AutoIndex/autoindex_dk_samtykke_confirmit.html"              
          target="_blank" rel="noopener">dette samtykke</a>. 
          Det er frivilligt at deltage i undersøgelsen.
        </p>
      <p class="style2"> </p>
    </footer>
  </table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">

 
    <footer text-align="center" 
            ><p class="style2"><br />Klik <a href="^OptOut:ProjectLink^">her</a>, hvis du ikke ønsker at modtage flere invitationer til undersøgelsen.&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="style2">XX afdækker hvert år kundernes oplevelser i en række forskellige brancher. <a href="^OptOut:PanelLink^">Klik her</a>, hvis du ønsker at afmelde alle invitationer til XXs undersøgelser fremover.</p>
    <p class="style2">XX gennemfører XX. Ved at påbegynde din besvarelse accepterer du, at vi må indsamle og behandle dine data i henhold til <a href="https://survey.euro.confirmit.com/isa/POADNDJYMRIOOXCAEPPIMTPDIIFRGQCB/AutoIndex/autoindex_dk_samtykke_confirmit.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">dette samtykke</a>. Det er frivilligt at deltage i undersøgelsen.</p>
        <p class="style2"> </p>
    </footer>


css...
footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
    /* background-color: DarkSalmon;
    color: white; */
    
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful can edit bg-color and text-color in the css file